# How to fetch all data by parent in dynamic dependent laravel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Here I've created a function for fetch data to dropdown list dynamically here when choosing a parent the child will work fine but what I want by default need to fetch all data to the child so I can go with child data only but whenever I choose the parent need to work as before so how can I do that? I'm a beginner to ajax

Edited - I have a parent dropdown called 'category' and the parent data come from database dynamically and I have a child dropdown called 'item' so I need to include option call 'all' so when I choose all need to fetch all child data so how can do that.

Blade :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <!-- general form elements -->
      <div class="box box-success">
         <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">Item Details Form</h3>
         </div>
         <!-- /.box-header -->
         <div class="box-body">
            <table class="table display dataTable" id="tableAddPurchaseList">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>Category</th>
                     <th>Item</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  @include('admin.purchase.tr_add_purchase', ['id' => 'addPurchaseListForm', 'class' => 'hide'])
                  @include('admin.purchase.tr_add_purchase')
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
         <!-- /.box-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.box -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Second blade :

```
<tr {{isset($id)?'id='.$id.'':''}} {{isset($class)?'class='.$class.'':''}}>
    <td>
        {!! Form::select('category_id[]', $item_categories, null, ['class'=>'form-control item_category_id select2']) !!}
    </td>
    <td>
        {!! Form::select('item_id[]', [''=>'Select'], null, ['class'=>'form-control item_id select2']) !!}
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Script :

```
$('body').on('change', '.item_category_id', function() {
        var $parent = $(this).parents('tr');
        var postData = {
            _token : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            category_id : $parent.find('.item_category_id').val(),
        };

        var select = $parent.find('.item_id');
        select.empty();
        select.append($('<option/>').val('').text('Select'));

        $.post(PHP_TO_JS.CURRENT_URL + '/admin/purchase/ajaxGetItemByCatIdBraId', postData, function(data){
                //do something
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(data) {
                    for(var i in data) {
                        select.append($('<option/>').val(data[i].id).text(data[i].title));
                    }
                }
            });

    });
```

Controller

```
public function ajaxGetItemByCatIdBraId(Request $request)
{
     $items = Item::select('id', 'title')
     ->where('category_id', $request->get('category_id'))
     ->get();

     echo json_encode($items);
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error? in network tab of developers tool?

Comment: @Webinion no sir

Comment: ohh, then what you can do is that pass one variable like `$item_categories`, which contains all child elements as array. just like you did in parent dropdown.

Comment: See my edited question, please.

Comment: sorry, not getting what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Webinion Sorry to confusing you, see my new edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did like this and it's working now

Controller get method :

```
public function getCreate()
    {
        $item = new Item();
        $item_categories = [''=>'Select'] + ['value'=>'All'] + ItemCategory::pluck('category', 'id')->toArray();

        return view('admin.purchase.create_edit', compact('item','item_categories'));
    }
```

Controller post method :

```
public function ajaxGetItemByCatIdBraId(Request $request)
    {
        $all_item = $request->category_id;
        if ($all_item == "value"){
         $items = Item::select('id', 'title')
         ->get();

         echo json_encode($items);
        }
        else {
        $items = Item::select('id', 'title')
        ->where('category_id', $request->get('category_id'))
        ->get();

        echo json_encode($items);
        }
    }
```